# How do I handle multiple web requests one at a time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails application, can I jump one action to another action while running one action?

As example, when I call the `create` method, I call the destroy method at the same time. I can see that it first executes `create`  then the `destroy` method.

Is there any way I can block the `create` method of my controller and jump to `destroy`  and again back to `create`?

Comment: this is not how controller actions are designed to work.

Comment: Actually He wants to concurrent access of controller actions.

Comment: Please clarify your question...

Comment: @badal as per rails design ....it is not yet possible to break the execution of a controller action and enter into another controller action at same time but ...it is a good thought....thanks

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you mean. Perhaps providing some code showing what you want to accomplish would help.

Comment: Can't think of an example where this would make sense, as controller actions are tied to specific routes in your app.
If you have repetetive behaviour in two or more actions, extract it to a (private) method instead. Everything else would fight the framework, which usually isn't a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Running `rails s` on a project only allows you to handle one web request at a time. However, you should not be using this in production.

In production, use something like [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) which automatically start multiple processes as needed so that you don't have to wait on a process to complete another user's action.

Hope that helps!